# Persisting objects from memory during debug session

Tags: software-development, .net, json, visual-studio, debugging

During a debugging session in .NET code, I identified a bug that occurs in seldom situations only. I was able to identify an object that can reproduce the behavior.

Now, I'd like to persist that .NET object including its sub-objects into a file so that I can re-use it in a test, likely a unit test.

The file format could e.g. be JSON, since it's very simple to read a JSON file and create an object structure (e.g. with JSON.NET). However, it could be any format, as long as there's some support for loading the object into memory again. That support could be part of the tool.

The tool that can do this has to integrate in Visual Studio 2015 and above. It needn't be free. If that's its sole feature, I would probably not pay too much. But it may come with other features, so in the end I might spend $200 or more.